# Codeception configs for various environments? (prod, dev, etc..)

Tags: codeception

I am creating various tests with codeception - especially acceptance tests where I test the frontend or an API. The problem ist that on my local machine I am using a webserver with a port 8080 on the test server the port is 9000.

Is there a way I can dynamically set the WebDriver url? In php or another yml file. Right now the URL is set in `acceptance.suite.yml` and it looks like this:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
           url: 'http://localhost:8080/myapp'
           browser: phantomjs
```

When I run this test on my test machine, all the tests fail (of course) because the server is running on port 9000 and not 8080.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using .env files for exactly this reason.

https://barryvanveen.nl/blog/36-environment-configuration-in-codeception-with-dotenv